# Disk space Prediction using R

Tags: r, prediction

```
I have 2 vectors 
days = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
pct_used = c(22.3, 22.1, 22.1, 22.1, 55.660198413, 56.001746032, 55.988769841)

fit <- lm(days ~ poly(pct_used,2,raw=TRUE))
prediction <- predict(fit, data.frame(pct_used=85))
days_remain <- (prediction - tail(days,1))
```

pct_used is basically disk space . So this code predicts when disk space will reach 85.
The prediction value returned is 325.something which is wierd I feel.Does that mean it will take 325 days to reach pct_used = 85 ?
Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Yes . The last 3 lines are R

Comment: If you are trying to predict Y then don't stick the value of Y in where X should be.

Comment: You made your prediction with `poly()` and then predicted way outside the range of values. What did you expect?

Comment: @Dwin i expected to get value < 15 .. meaning in that many days pct_used will reach 85

Comment: If i flip x and y , it gives me an array ...

Comment: What made you think you could do polynomial regression with so few points and do a prediction that that was outside the range of support of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see what is happening:

```
plot(pct_used, days)
lines(pct_used, predict(fit
```

[image]

```
plot(pct_used, days, xlim=c(min(pct_used), 85) ,ylim= c(-50,350))
lines(seq(min(pct_used), 85, length=50), predict(fit, newdata=data.frame( 
                                        pct_used=seq( min(pct_used), 85, length=50))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I have embedded the code in Ruby yusing RinRuby gem .. cant plot in Ruby, just compute using R .. I wanted to feed R with some values(pct_used) and predict when that pct_used will reach 85. Any ideas ?

Comment: My idea is that you should reconsider your strategy, and you should explain what is really going on. (Pasted in the graphic I was looking at.)

Comment: Sorry, I just cant generate graphs .. i tried plotting using ur code suggested but nothing appears .. My idea is pull the disk space values (in % like node has reach 42% of its disk consumption, next point 45 , next point 55... and so on .. and find point when it will reach 85% of its disk consumption).. Thanks lot of offering help